# How can I edit or rename a PHAssetCollection LocalizedTitle?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, phasset, phphotolibrary

I want to change the albumName in my app.

```
if ([collection canPerformEditOperation:PHCollectionEditOperationRename]  == YES)
    {
        //rename localizedTitle
    }
```

If that is "YES", I want to change the name.

My code is:

```
PHFetchOptions *userAlbumsOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
userAlbumsOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"estimatedAssetCount > 0"];

PHFetchResult *userAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAny options:userAlbumsOptions];

[userAlbums enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAssetCollection *collection, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
 {

 }];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
-(void)changeAlbumtitle:(PHAssetCollection *)collection withTitle:(NSString *)title {

    if (![collection canPerformEditOperation:PHCollectionEditOperationRename]) {

        NSLog(@"can't PerformEditOperation");
        return;
    }


    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *changeTitlerequest =[PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:collection];
        changeTitlerequest.title = title;


    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Finished editing collection. %@", (success ? @"Successfully." : error));
    }];


}
```

In Above give function pass the album object (PHAssetCollection ) and title

- First the function check PHAssetCollection can perform rename
  editOperation
- If edit operation is possible then implement PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest and set the new title.